# Compare two arrays and re-arrange the ordering SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two variables in SQL. I need to rearrange the `tbl2` based on `tbl1`. Every an item in `tbl1` is there on `tbl2`.

```
DECLARE @tbl1 VARCHAR(MAX) = '["A","B","C"]' 
DECLARE @tbl2 VARCHAR(MAX) = '["X","A","D","C","B"]'
```

What I want is `tbl2` re-ordering to -->

```
[ "A", "B", "C", "X", "D" ]
```

I have tried like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl1 VARCHAR(MAX) = '["A","B","C"]';
DECLARE @tbl2 VARCHAR(MAX) = '["X","A","D","C","B"]';

DECLARE @json1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = JSON_QUERY(@tbl1);
DECLARE @json2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = JSON_QUERY(@tbl2);

DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @ResultTable (Value)
    SELECT j.Value
    FROM OPENJSON(@json1) j1
    JOIN OPENJSON(@json2) j2 ON j1.Value = j2.Value
    ORDER BY j1.[key];

DECLARE @ResultJson NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT Value
    FROM @ResultTable
    FOR JSON PATH
);

PRINT @ResultJson;
```

Comment: and why is it tagged c# and asp?

Comment: @nbk It isn't now 

Answer (score 0):

You can just left-join the two `OPENJSON` sets by `value`, then order by the `key` (after casting to `int`).

Unfortunately, `JSON_ARRAYAGG` is not yet available, so you need to hack it with `STRING_AGG` and `STRING_ESCAPE`.

```sql
SELECT
  '["' +
  STRING_AGG(STRING_ESCAPE(j2.value, 'json'), '","')
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ISNULL(CAST(j1.[key] AS int), 1000000)) +
  '"]'
FROM OPENJSON(@tbl2) j2
LEFT JOIN OPENJSON(@tbl1) j1 ON j2.value = j1.value;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/wHA1aVKh)

| Result |
| --- |
| ["A","B","C","X","D"] |